# iPhone: Freeform XIB file doens't fit in iPhone view

Tags: iphone, xib, freeform

I have created XIB file in freeform size because I need many controls to add. I have done it but when I push my view controller, it doesn't have automatic scrollbar on iPhone display and my view gets cropped! How to get my full view displayed on iPhone?

I have set view frame on view load but that doesn't make any difference!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600)];
}
```

Following looks like cycling between view and scrollview worked for me! Not a good solution though!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,600);
[self.view setFrame:frame];
self.scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.scrollview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.scrollview addSubview:self.view];
self.scrollview.contentSize = frame.size;
self.view = self.scrollview;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at `UIScrollView`.  Within the `UIScrollView` add a `UIView` for your content.  You then need to set the content size of the `UIScrollView` to enable scrolling.

Example:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,600);
UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

// Add objects to view

[self.scrollView addSubview:subView];
self.scrollView.contentSize = frame.size;
```

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 1):

You have to take different approach for this case.

You need to add a UIScrollView to your controller's view - make it take the whole screen and then inside the scroll view you can add as much content as you wish - this way your form will be scrollable and the user can go up and down to see all the controls inside the form

Comment: No I tried that it didn't work either! :( I always write code in ViewDid load but this time I have created controls in XIB file and don't know how to show it now! We never create UIScrollView while creating controls from code but it still works. Isn't it?